# How can I set SATA controller mode in my PC?

Tags: bios, sata

I have a HP Compaq Presario CQ43 notebook. But I haven't found there SATA controller mode in my PC's BIOS setup. Now what should I do?

Comment: You might explain your real problem or what you are trying to do that requires this change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to [AHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface).

Most computer bios can configure the sata controller to work either in IDE mode or AHCI (some will also propose "RAID")

IDE mode provide compatibility for operating systems that don't support AHCI natively (altough most of time you can install an AHCI driver).

AHCI offers better performances.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops have a rather limited firmware, meaning that you can get into the BIOS setup (or these days EFI setup) but that you do not get many choices.

This is not a problem, as long as the defaults are wisely choosen and there is no need to change them.

> Now what should I do?

Nothing. The only sensible setting is AHCI mode and that is probably what is set.

You only need to change these settings if you want to install some software which does has no drivers for a normal SATA AHCI setup and which needs the SATA driver to be reconfigured into ancient compatability mode. E.g. if you want to install windows 98 or similar old stuff.